# What is the maximum number of CSV files I can merge into one file on Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need to merge more than 800 CSV files that have an identical structure into 1 file on Azure Data Lake Storage GEN2 using a ADF pipeline. Up to how many files can I merge into one and what is the recommended maximum size of the output file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Up to how many files can I merge into one?

There might not be no limit on the number of files that can be merged into a single file. The following is a demonstration where I have merged up to **10,000 files** into one single file.

- The copy data activity merge:

[image]

- The output:

[image]

> what is the recommended maximum size of the output file?

- Since you are merging your files to store it in Azure Data Lake gen2 storage, this data lake storage allows you to store up to 5TB for a single file with few performance limitations.
- According to this official Microsoft documentation for [Best practices for using Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-best-practices#:%7E:text=Parquet%20file%20formats.-,File%20size,-Larger%20files%20lead), storing many small files reduce performance (*which is not the case here*). A file with size greater than 100GB also reduces efficiency. Therefore, it is recommended that the optimal output file size would be something **less than 100GB**.